# Is "try taking these ones" correct? (doctor speaking to a patient)

Tags: word-choice

A patient is complaining that the pills that he had given her a week ago don't help, so he opens a drawer, takes another pack of some other pills and says: "Try taking these ones".

Is it correct to say like this? Does it sound natural?

Comment: "Try these" or "Try these pills instead" would be my preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having been informed of a Question Update, here is my new answer.

**(try + to V)**

We use this to indicate difficulty in the activity given by the verb. for example, if some one is lying on the floor complaining of an injury to the leg, we might say

*try to stand up*

This indicates that, because of the purported injury, we do not yet know whether this person will be able to stand or not. Therefore, they should try and find out.

**(try v-ing)**

We use this when suggesting a solution to a problem. For example, if someone is beside you in the crowd of a sporting event or similar and they complain that they cannot see, you might respond

*try standing up*

Here you are suggesting the activity given by the verb. We know that the person is physically capable of standing up; we are suggesting that they 'try it out' to see what the results are.

---

Applying this to your example, 'try taking...' would appear to be correct since the doctor is probably not questioning your ability to swallow the pills but rather suggesting that they might solve your problem (i.e. make you feel better).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Millsom - Thank you Karl. That's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: More than welcom, @brilliant.

Answer (score 4):

I was always taught to use "these" instead of "these ones."

Comment: @jellybeanrancher -- I wasn't taught this, per se, but it is what I do.

Comment: +1; I was strictly taught to say, "these" instead of "these ones" to the point of being told the latter was grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is grammatically correct:

> Try taking these pills.

"pills" is a plural noun
"ones" is a plural noun

Looks fine, technically, to me.

I would say it's fairly unnatural, though.

Comment: @advs89: Thank you. So, what would you say in this situation if you were a doctor? I need a phrase that would sound absolutely natural.

Comment: Why not simply "Try taking these."  And you could have him/her go on to explain what they are and mention side effects and such.

Comment: although when I go to the doctor, it tends to go more like:  "I'm writing you a prescription for Zyrtec.  You'll take it twice a day with a meal until you run out."

Comment: Doctors tend to try and sound "professional" even if it isn't completely natural, in my experience.

Comment: I think whether "these ones" sounds more natural, in a colloquial context, is dialect-related - certainly it sounds fine to me (from the south of England), but my father (from the north) used to find this strange and prefer "these".

Comment: @psmears thanks! Sounds a bit strange to me, "these ones", but interesting that somewhere this sounds natural.

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly correct to say "Try taking these ones." Also, in this situation, this statement sounds entirely natural. One might also hear, "Try these."

Answer (score 2):

I think *these ones* rather than just *these* implies there's ***some specific attribute*** applicable to each of the proffered alternatives, suggesting they've been ***individually checked*** and found to have the required attribute. So a greengrocer might refer to some specially selected apples as *these ones* if you didn't fancy the scabby ones originally offered.

A doctor might not be *likely* to use this construction to refer to an alternative pack of pills (which he presumably hasn't opened and examined / selected individually! :). But the implication described above is a *very* fine nuance of meaning that won't necessarily be either intended *or* understood - I certainly wouldn't go so far as to *criticize* OP's cited usage.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @FumbleFingers that the inclusion of 'ones' seems to add emphasis on a difference between the old pills and the new (ones).

I'm not quite sure why there is so much question over 'these ones' from the other posters as I have always thought it ok. Nevertheless, if you really do want to avoid it but still want to emphasise the difference, maybe go for:

*Try these instead.*

---

If I asked which one should I choose, you might answer:

*Try these*

If I then tried them and they were no good and I asked for a replacement, you might respond:

*Try these instead*

---

Just to reiterate, I see no problem with 'these ones' and would even be happy with:

*Try these ones instead*

Comment: I wasn't specific enough when I was asking this question, and, therefore, the answers that I have received here have mostly dealt with another aspect of my question, which also turned out to be quite interesting. However, my original intention was to find out whether "*try taking*" was grammatically and stylistically correct. Somebody had told me that using an "on- *ing* -ending" verb right after "*try*" was not a good choice of words, especially if it's the verb "*taking*" in the sense of receiving something into one's body (like swallowing medicine).